# from ng-repeat how to get the scope values of each iterated tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
      <button ng-click="call('d')">for d</button>
      <button ng-click="call('f')">for f</button>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in a[replace]">{{ngController}}
          {{x}}<div><input  ng-model=well ng-click=fun()>{{well}}</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.a = {
          d:[1,2,3,4,5],
          f:[6,7,8,9]
        };
        $scope.call = function(val) {
          $scope.replace=val;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here I have give ng-scope, which is being iterated. Now I want to get access to those particular scopes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
                <button ng-click="call('d')">for d</button>
                <button ng-click="call('f')">for f</button>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in a[replace]">{{ngController}}
                        {{x}}<div><input  ng-model=well ng-click=fun(well)>{{well}}</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <script>
                var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
                    $scope.a = {
                        d:[1,2,3,4,5],
                        f:[6,7,8,9]
                    };
                    $scope.call = function(val) {
                        $scope.replace=val;
                    }
                    $scope.fun = function(vl){alert(vl)}
                });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```